# Generating Line between two draggable Divs using jquery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kineticjs

I need to join the two given elements ( Say double click / highlight two elements and join them using a line )

I heard this could be achieved using jsplumb and raphealjs. Any other straight way to succeed in this or by using Kineticjs. Please find my fiddle below in the comment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scvikram/fvS8K/1/)

Comment: It looks like the libraries you mentioned are ideal for what you need.  I suggest you look at the documentation for them and have a go yourself before asking here.

Comment: Hi thanks for  your earnest response. The elements what I intend  to link using connecting are not inside canvas since they are cloned elements . I am unable to clone inside canvas.  So they are inside the div. Now I need to apply the features of canvas to a non-canvas element. I did go through jsplumb and raphaeljs before posting this question but didn't help much.